send communication notification with FCM for IOS in Flutter
I want to send notifications to iOS devices from a server using Python's FCM package. I'd like these notifications to display the sender's image instead of the application icon. I wondering if there's a way to include the sender's image in the notification payload so that the application can automatically show it in the communication notification.
message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'type': '0',
        'title':'Hello',
        'body':'This is a test notification',
        'icon': f"{sender_image_notification}"
    },
    token=f'{user_token}'
)


Based on the fact that in your question you have mentioned "..instead of the application icon..", I surmise you have not added an image to your push payload and are trying to change the 'default' image (which is the app-icon) that appears on the top row of a notification. You cannot change this to be the sender image. You can set an image different from the app icon in the asset catalog but it will be fixed for a given build and cannot be changed programmatically. A better way would be to follow the answer below by '@Jayce Nguyen' and implement a notification service extension.

You can add any image URL to your push payload, this would be the sender's picture that you want to show up in the notification. You would then add a new target to your project, this new target would be a notification service extension. You would receive the push payload in this extension, extract the URL from it, download the image, and append it to the notification object as an attachment, which the system will then use to display on the right hand side of the push notification banner. If the user tap-holds on the push, the notification will expand and show a bigger version of this image.

You need to add a Notification extension service into your Xcode runner
then you can custom your notification with that service.
There are many tutorials you can search on google but i'm suggest you read the Apple documentation first
